# How to create a shortcut for a tab in Console2?

Tags: git, tabs, shortcut, git-bash, console2

In Console2, I have 2 tabs. The first is called "Console2" and it's the default tab. The second is called "Git Bash" and it's the Console2 replacement for Git Bash CMD.

I would like to create a shortcut to the tab "Git Bash". So every time I click this shortcut. I open Console2 with the tab "Git Bash". The current Console2 default tab is "Console2" and I hope to keep it that way.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution at Console2 forum [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/forums/forum/143117/topic/5278234/index/page/1)

To create a shortcut for a tab, create a Windows shortcut with the Target field set with

> "C:\path\to\Console.exe" -t "Tab Name"

Answer (score 1):

another method is using batch file

create a yadayada.bat file with this content:

```
start /d "D:\.....\Desktop\Console2" Console.exe -t "tab1" -t "tab2" -t "tab3"
```